# Error setting up a virtualenv with jython 2.7b3

Tags: virtualenv, jython, jython-2.7

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment using jython 2.7b3. I'm running Mac OS 10.8.5 in case that's relevant.

I installed virtualenv (1.11.6) using jython and easy_install as recommended here: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixA.html

But when I run:

```
$ /usr/local/jython/jython2.7b3/bin/virtualenv jython-venv
```

I get the output:

```
Cannot find file /usr/local/jython/jython2.7b3/Include (bad symlink)
New jython executable in jython-venv/bin/jython
ERROR: The executable jython-venv/bin/jython is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/usr/local/jython/jython2.7b3' (should be  u'/..../jython-venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

(Where `/..../jython-venv` stands for the path to the new virtual environment I created.)

When I run `jython-venv/bin/jython` I get a normal jython prompt:

```
$ jython-venv/bin/jython
Jython 2.7b3 (default:e81256215fb0, Aug 4 2014, 02:39:51) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_51
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What am I missing? Why does virtualenv think the executable doesn't work, even though it seems to be functioning OK by itself? Is it just a matter of telling it the correct `sys.prefix`? If so how can I do that?

Many thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Here's a pro tip: avoid Jython.  Basic happy path scenarios are ridden with bugs.  The worst part: the dev team is fully aware as seen on their bug tracker, but comes up with wonky workarounds or points the finger at 3rd party libs, instead of fixing it.  Basic utilities like `pipenv`, `virtualenv`, are broken out of the box (due to environment variables set by the installer!).  And even the interactive shell is broken (yes, running plain old `jython` from a fresh install) because they're using obsolete terminal abstractions which can't handle modern `xterm-256color` setting.  Garbage!!!

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem and solution described here: 
http://seletz.github.io/blog/2012/04/06/jython-classpath-virtualenv/

Apparently there is a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/185) in virtualenv that causes this issue when `JYTHON_HOME` is set, which was my problem.

As soon as it's unset with `unset JYTHON_HOME`, virtualenv works (almost) as expected.

```
$ echo $JYTHON_HOME
/usr/local/jython/jython2.7b3
$ unset JYTHON_HOME
$ echo $JYTHON_HOME
```

I say "almost" as expected because it still had an issue installing pip. Luckily that problem and its solution described here: https://gist.github.com/skyl/ea2ab1c62a547e381411

Comment: I don't have `JYTHON_HOME` set, still getting the issue. Any clues?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Avoid Jython, it's a terrible project with a ton of bugs they won't fix.